# 405 Method not allowed in Spring Boot and Ajax

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hi I am having request mapping like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pendodnp/{visitorId}/{content}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> setPendoDNP(@PathVariable String visitorId, @PathVariable String content, final HttpSession session, final HttpServletRequest request) throws PendoException {
    LOGGER.info("### pendodnp");
    _splitService.updateDNP(visitorId, content);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(content);
}
```

but when I hit this URL from an angular function, it gives "405 method not allowed" error.

```
    $http.get("pendodnp/"+visitorId+"/"+dnpValue, JSON.stringify(dnpValue))
        .success(function(response) {
```

Here is screenshot of how the request is going, can someone tell me what i am missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc) the mapping should handle. To do that either use `@GetMapping` or change your `@RequestMapping` so it includes the `method` parameter.

```java
@GetMapping("/pendodnp/{visitorId}/{content}")
```

Or

```java
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;
...
@RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/pendodnp/{visitorId}/{content}")
```

Using `@RequestMapping` without a `method` parameter is usually only done at the *class* level, not individual methods. `@GetMapping` (or `@PostMapping`, `@PutMapping`, etc) are more common on controller *methods*.